# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted while installing ionic and cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have spent the last few hours trying to install ionic and cordova but I keep getting the error below. I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it, i tried clearing the cache and setting the environmental variables to the correct path. Has anyone faced this issue before ?

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\noor\eggly-ionic\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **[Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx)**.

1. In the **Start** Search box, type **cmd**.
2. Right-click **Command prompt**, and then click **Run as administrator**.
3. If the **User Account Control** dialog box appears, confirm that the
   action it displays is what you want, and then click **Continue**.

Also, be sure to disable your anti-malware and antivirus software temporarily.